# Higher rank lifetimes and generics not playing nicely

Tags: rust, closures, traits, lifetime

In the code here

```
trait Foo {
    type Output;
    fn foo(self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<'a> Foo for &'a () {
    type Output = &'a ();
    fn foo(self) -> Self::Output {
        self
    }
}

fn func<F: Foo>(f: F) -> F::Output {
    f.foo()
}

fn func2<'a>(f: &'a ()) -> &'a () {
    func::<&'a ()>(f)
}

fn has_hrl<F: Fn(&()) -> &()>(f: F) {}

fn main() {
    //has_hrl(func); // FAILS
    has_hrl(func2);
    has_hrl(|x| func(x));
}
```

We would like to do `has_hrl(func)`, but Rust only accepts the closure `has_hrl(|x| func(x))`. Why is that? Because it works with concrete types like in `func2`, but not with generic types.

Comment: This would work if you declared `has_hrl` like `fn has_hrl<'a, F: Fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()>(_: F) {}`. My power level is insufficient to explain why the lifetime needs to be explicit, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this expression:

```
has_hrl(func)
```

The compiler is forced to pick one specific instance of `func`. `func` is generic over `F: Foo`, and for all `'a`, `&'a ()` implements `Foo`, but the compiler can only choose one particular `'a` to instantiate `func`, because a type variable cannot represent a multitude of types. Therefore, `func::<&'a ()>` does not implement `for<'a> Fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()`, it only implements `Fn(&'x ()) -> &'x ()` for one specific lifetime `'x`.

> This would work if you declared `has_hrl` like `fn has_hrl<'a, F: Fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()>(_: F) {}`. My power level is insufficient to explain why the lifetime needs to be explicit, though. – [ljedrz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870153/ljedrz)

That's because the original declaration has an implied higher-ranked lifetime bound (the bound is equivalent to `F: for<'a> Fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()`), which means that `F` must implement `Fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()` for *all* lifetimes `'a`. Your version only requires `F` to implement `Fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()` for one concrete lifetime. You'll also find that this version doesn't work if `has_hrl` tries to call the closure with a lifetime that is local to the `has_hrl` function, because the caller cannot possibly pass that lifetime as a parameter (which is why higher-ranked lifetime bounds were introduced).

Comment: I just tried splitting the statement `has_hrl(|x| func(x));` into 2 statements: `let f = |x| func(x); has_hrl(f);` and the same error shows up. Somehow appearing as an argument is handled differently from a variable binding (a binding should be pinned to a fully concrete type). So I am guessing even Higher Ranked Lifetimes are not yet well-captured by Rust's current type system (and uses some kinda tricks behind the scenes)?

Comment: I understand that it has higher ranked lifetimes, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work, it seems like this is something that should work.

Comment: @iopq: [You're not alone...](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/higher-kinded-types-the-difference-between-giving-up-and-moving-forward/3908/4)

Comment: Your first part isn't quite correct. The compiler *can* instantiate a single `func::<&'a ()>` for all `'a`; it's doing exactly this inside `func2`. That is, rustc instantiates exactly one copy of `func2` which means there must exist a single `func::<&'a ()>` valid for all `'a`. Unfortunately, rustc doesn't appear to expose this fact in the type system.

Comment: @Steven: It's true that there is a single `func::<&'a ()>` for all `'a`, as lifetime parameters are [erased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure), unlike type parameters. This may be why we have higher-rank lifetimes but not higher-rank types (e.g. `for<T> Fn(T)`), which might be more complex to implement.